# MS Access Queries open in small window, only 8 row

Tags: ms-access

Regarding 2003: When opening a query, to say enter date for a selection from a table, the window always opens with only 8 rows of data showing.

I would like to, ideally, have it open to full available height of the container window, but the width sized for the fields configured to show. That may be a tall order, so would settle to have the window open the way it was last closed, or at least maximized.

Can't find anything on the Internet regarding to window sizing for MS Access Query Windows. Lots of info on forms.  I can't find anything on window size, or number of rows to display settings for Queries. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
There is an answer to this, and it has nothing to do with an ini file for msaccess.

The query window relevant to the subject, is opened via a DoCmd command from a form. The form is used to set up search parameters that are sent to the query.

A parameter in the DoCmd, such as "acViewNormal" or acNormal, does provide query window size control. However there is no save of the last open query window size, when the query is closed to go back to the form.

This happens only when you open the query in design mode, make changes, and save the query. But the change has to be functionally significant. A simple cosmetic change, such as only a window resizing, is not enough for the save to actually save anything. I put a couple of quotes in a criteria row, hit enter, and then removed them. That forces a full save of the query, including the window size.

When the query is then opened via the DoCmd command from the form, the window size is as it was when the query was saved. (almost; msaccess, in it['s own wisdom, does make a small adjustment).

Comment: Advise to work with form, not directly with table or query, for data entry/edit. Is db set for Tabbed Documents or Overlapping Windows?

Comment: The form would be the answer for window size control.  However, I was working on a one-of project that took only three hours.  For that I didn't want to spend the time creating a form. As a quick data edit/add the query work very well.  It's easy to change the filter, etc.  It's only the repetitively small window size that's the problem.  But please let me know if you have any other concern about using queries for data entry/add?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access 2003 but even in previous versions queries would keep the size that you set while in design view. Set the proper size and save the query. 
Size will be overridden if you select to maximize the view (which will then be applied for any query you open).

To have more control on the insertion process a form is usually the best approach. This will allow you to control how data are shown, suggestions to the users and checks on inserted data,

Comment: That's exactly what I expected, that the window generally open as "last closed".  I recently rebuilt my system (yes, I installed off 2003, it does everything I want), and since the last rebuild, msaccess simply opens queries with 8 rows of data. Never the last open state.  As mentioned above, if I had a longer project then I would create a form, but for short jobs the query is OK.  I rebuild my system every 6 months or so , maybe the next time msaccess will behave different.  I remember something about an ini file for access.  I'll have to investigate and get back.